# Why fftw always undefined reference in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fftw

I'm trying to use fftw in vscode. And the language is C++. I'm doing this in WSL.
I just do this just by code runner...like as

```
g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "/home/linhuan/CPP/homework/homework_6/"tempCodeRunnerFile
```

So it should be with g++.But it always shows me:

```
/usr/bin/ld: sun.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
/usr/bin/ld: sun.cpp:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `fftw_plan_dft_1d'
/usr/bin/ld: sun.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `fftw_execute'
/usr/bin/ld: sun.cpp:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `fftw_destroy_plan'
/usr/bin/ld: sun.cpp:(.text+0x1de): undefined reference to `fftw_free'
/usr/bin/ld: sun.cpp:(.text+0x1ed): undefined reference to `fftw_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have done as http://www.fftw.org/doc/Installation-on-Unix.html#Installation-on-Unix:

./configure ,make,make install

And I don't know how to deal with it. I'm a newer for this...

And my code is:

```
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int N,i=0;
    vector<double> input;
    ifstream data("sunspots.txt");
    double d;
    while (data >> d){
        if(i%2==1){
            input.push_back(d);
        }
        i++;
    }
    N=input.size();
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;
    in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        in[i][0]=input[i];
        in[i][1]=0.0;
    }
    fftw_execute(p); 
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        cout<<i<<in[i][0]<<" "<<in[i][1]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The sunspot.txt is like that:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
```

Comment: The important step (which you don't seem to describe, apologies if I missed something) is how you build the program that gives you the undefined references. To me it looks that you are simply not linking with the fftw library.

Comment: maybe you are right,but how can I use fftw3.h just #include?@john

Comment: I don't look at it at stackoverflow or somewhere else, can you give me a website? Thank you for help whatever

Comment: You need to give the linker the name of the library. `#include "fftw3.h"` is for the compiler, but you need to tell the linker as well. For g++ that would be an option something like `-lfftw3` (but don't quote me I'm just guessing).

Comment: See this [page](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Data-Types-and-Files.html#Data-Types-and-Files). The linker options you need are clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as

```
g++ sun.cpp -lfftw3 -lm
```